# PyQt5 how to override append text from QTextBrowser

Tags: python, pyqt5

I was wondering about how to override the latest printed `str` in my QTextBrowser. The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTextBrowser.html) could not help me very much for my problem.

I first want to print this line: `Downloading:  Nr: 1 KG Nr. 1 Grst.Nr.: 1 Status: pending`

I tried using `\r` like in the console, but it did not work (I already thought of that). It only printed a separate line between a loop iteration. This is the string I'm using:

```
insert_row = f'Downloading:  Nr: {element.excel_ref_number:<10}' +\
                f' KG Nr.: {element.kg_nr:<10}' +\
                f' Grst. Nr.: {element.grst_nr:<20}' +\
                f' Status: {status:<5}\r'
self.mySignal.emit(insert_row)
```

After some operations it should change the status from *pending* into *done*. Which should look like something like this: `Downloading:  Nr: 1 KG Nr. 1 Grst.Nr.: 1 Status: done`

I'm using a signal to return this strings and to display it's status into the main window `t_begin.mySignal.connect(self.output_pte.append)`.

Comment: So, you want to *replace* the last line with the new one? Besides, why are you using QTextBrowser?

Comment: Yeah and after that a new row should be printed, which does not override the last line. I'm using this for the benefit of hypertext, which I want to use later in the project

Comment: With "new row" do you mean a new line character? Should it always replace the last line, or only the last line that has the previous "pending" status? Are there going to be other lines with different content? You didn't explain why you're using QTextBrowser, though.

Comment: Yeah it should print `Downloading:  Nr: 1 KG Nr. 1 Grst.Nr.: 1 Status: pending` while it is proccesing after it finished it should replace the *pending* with *done*. After that a new line should be printed with `Downloading:  Nr: 2 KG Nr. 2 Grst.Nr.: 2 Status: pending` and so on.
I use QTextBrowser to have hyperlinks which I can link to a file.